# Mouse over open popup, mouse out close popup, popup moue over should not close popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

mouse over i'm opening one popup, mouse out i'm closing popup. but inside that popup mouse over it should not close. popup is closing.
except menu mouse over and popup mouse over , where ever you mouse over it should close. sorry for my english .please suggest someone how to do this  better. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/varunphp/upd5p7yp/)

i'm find out one way but this is not correct way.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href='css/nprogress.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" id="main_content">
<div id="mouse_over" class="showingMenuCity" style="background: red; padding: 10px; width: 150px; float: right;">Mouse over Menu</div>
<div style="height: 450px; background: green;"></div>
<script>
$(function(){

    $('#mouse_over').mouseover(function(){
        $("#video").slideDown("slow");
    });
    $('#main_content').mouseover(function(event){
        var targetClassName=event.target.className;
        if(targetClassName.indexOf("showingMenuCity") >=0){

        }else{
            $("#video").slideUp("slow");
        }
     });
});
</script>


<div class="container showingMenuCity" id="video" >
   <div class="row showingMenuCity">
    <div class="col-sm-12 showingMenuCity">
      <h3 class="showingMenuCity">Popular Cities</h3>
      <ul class="bsCityUl showingMenuCity">
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
        </ul>
      <h3 class="showingMenuCity">Other Cities</h3>
      <ul class="bsCityUl showingMenuCity">
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
        <li class="bsCityLs showingMenuCity">Chennai</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
.bsCityLs { float: left; margin: 2px 6px; list-style: none;  }
.bsCityUl { width: 100%;  }
#video
{
    background: #fff;
    display:none;
    width:35%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:-12px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Basically you have a menu bar, if you mouseover on one of the menu option you will get one popup/modal . Then inside that popup you would have some content . If you again mouse over that content , popup should be closed. This is what you want to say ? Correct me if am wrong

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle , So if you put cursor on " Popular Cities " popup should be closed ?

Comment: thats only i need Ramkee... ya popup is closing..

Comment: chrome contains not working so i'm using indeOf now error is not coming. -bnord

Comment: If you put cursor on " Popular Cities " popup will not close where as if you mouse over chennai popup will going to be closed. Have a look   https://jsfiddle.net/upd5p7yp/3/

Comment: I don't see the behavior you're describing. For me the popup stays open when I move the mouse from the menu div directly into the popup div. Both on Chrome & Firefox. Do you see a different behavior or what kind of behavior do you expect?

Comment: Probably Varun should say it in Hindi or Tamil and someone who knows that language should translate it here.

Comment: Yup, Varun if you know Telugu, you can talk to me.

Comment: Charlie put my popup html code in outside of main_content div so now its is working fine bnord. what i'm doing this is one write method or not.

Comment: inside popup mouse over not closing popup can you check , i know tamil little bit english -Ramkee

Comment: Yeah, i did. If you put your cursor on "chennai" then the popup will close.

Comment: Thank you much Charlie,bnord,ramkee,Evgeny Sorokin

Comment: Did you fix the issue ? can you update it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd propose you the following solution

```
$(function(){
    var videoNode = $('#video');

    $('#mouse_over').on('mouseenter',function(){
        videoNode.slideDown("slow");
    });

    videoNode.on('mouseleave', function(event){
        $(this).slideUp("slow");
     });
});
```

Bin:https://jsbin.com/bobuzo/edit?html,output